# Oracle : joining tables using conditions in ON clause

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables as follows:

```
    Parent                          Child   
ABID    DEPARTMENT TIME         ABID    ABDEPARTMENT 
1       SC          10          1       MC           
1       -ALL-       15          2       SY           
1       MC          20                     
2       SC          20                             
2       -ALL-       15                             
2       MC          20
```

I want to write a join query so that output of the query

1. should have matching ABID and Department.
2. If no matching department is present in Parent table, query should
   return the row with DEPARTMENT '-ALL-'

So the output in should be

```
ABID    DEPARTMENT TIME  ABID   ABDEPARTMENT
1          MC        20   1       MC
2        -ALL-       15   2       SY
```

**UPDATE1 :**

My current query is :

```
select * from Child LEFT join Parent on Child.AbId = Parent.AbId and Child.ABDEPARTMENT= Parent.DEPARTMENT
```

Which gives following output :

```
ABID    DEPARTMENT ABID ABDEPARTMENT TIME     
1          MC      1          MC      20
2          SY      NULL      NULL     NULL
```

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: I have updated my current query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
select *
  from parent p
  join child c on p.abid = c.abid and c.abdepartment = p.department
 union
select *
  from parent p
  join child c on p.abid = c.abid and p.department = '-ALL-'
 where not exists (select null
                     from parent p
                    where p.abid = c.abid
                      and c.abdepartment = p.department)
```